# OS boots into Emergency mode - fsck says its clean

Tags: boot, 16.04, fsck, systemd-journald

So I have multipath setup and it seems like if I enable  multipath partition in fstab, then everytime the reboots, it goes into emergency mode.

If I disable that in fstab, then server reboots fine.

I ran fsck.ocfs2 /dev/mapper/mpatha-part1 and it says it is clean.

```
    cat /etc/fstab | grep mpath
    /dev/mapper/mpatha-part1 /mnt/test ocfs2 defaults 0 0
```

On the console, It shows

```
    Started LSB: Load O2CB cluster services at system boot..
    Starting LSB: Mount OCFS2 volume at boot

    Welcome to emergency mode: type journalctl -xb
```

In journalctl I saw it stated:

```
    mount[1077]: mount.cfs2: Unable to access cluster service while trying initialize cluster
    systemd[1]: mnt-origin.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=1
    systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/test.
```

But after I login to Emergency mode, I see that /mnt/test has mounted successfully.

Any suggestions on what to look for next?